# C# Windows Service can't find namespace of dll, works in other projects

Tags: c#, dll, windows-services

This is a weird one.

I created a new Windows Service in C#, and want to re-use some of the code we created before that's in a Class Library.

The project is loaded in the solution along with the service. Both target .NET Framework 4.0 (not client profile).

I tried adding a project reference, and it worked for a short while. After working on some old code that I was rewriting, when the project compiled again, it complained that it no longer recognised the namespace for the using statement.

I've made sure to clean the solution & rebuild, but no dice. Sometimes VS can have a bad day, so I restarted VS, but this also didn't work.

I then build the DLL, and add a reference to it via 'browse', also no dice. Then I tested it on another project, but after adding it, it works instantly, so it's not the DLL.

I then checked with other libraries in the solution, but I was able to add a reference to them in the service and access their namespace without a problem.

I'm out of ideas here, anyone got an idea of what to do here?

Thanks,

Nick.

Almoast forgot: the weird thing is, that if I open up the Class view, and expand the 'References' section, the namespace/dll doesn't show up there either... it's a real conundrom...

Comment: Remove the ref, Clean Project, Add it again. Rebuild.

Comment: As described in my story, I already did that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I should pay more attention to warnings:

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1360,9): warning MSB3253: The referenced assembly "" could not be resolved because it has a dependency on "System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which is not in the currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client". Please remove references to assemblies not in the targeted framework or consider retargeting your project.

So, I'm a ready idiot for checking the DLL's target framework but not the Windows Service :)

The problem is my DLL uses System.Web, which is not part of the .NET 4 Client Profile framework target. Changing the Service's Target Framework to 4.0 fixed it.

Comment: happens to the best :) you should mark your own awnser as `awnser` to remove it from stack overflows unawnsered questions

Answer (score 0):

If the class view doesnt show the types that should be there, the actual dll you're compliling against is not the correct version.

There could be several reasons for this

- A previous compilation of the dll might still be around
- The project might reference another, older, binary version of the library rather than having a project reference
- Another project mgiht be referencing an old version of the dll, and have copy local set to `true`. When that project is compiled it overwrites the new version of the library

Make sure **all** projects in the solution use project references, and remove all binaries you can find.

Comment: Ready my own 'answer' post for the actual situation & solution